Get all defined attributes in a Map
Given the following properties of a Request Body:
...
post:
  requestBody:
    content:
      'multipart/form-data':
        schema:
          type: object
          properties:
            foo:
              type: string
            bar:
              type: boolean
            baz:
              type: integer
            ...

The OpenAPI Generator for Maven (7.4.0) configuration follows (paying attention to the generatorName and configOptions:useSpringBoot3 values, spring and true, respectively):
...
              <configuration>
                <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/swagger/api.yml</inputSpec>
                <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                <apiPackage>com.company.service.web.api</apiPackage>
                <modelPackage>com.company.service.api.dto</modelPackage>
                <supportingFilesToGenerate>ApiUtil.java</supportingFilesToGenerate>
                <importMappings>
                  <importMapping>Problem=org.zalando.problem.Problem</importMapping>
                  <importMapping>OffsetDateTime=java.time.Instant</importMapping>
                </importMappings>
                <typeMappings>
                  <typeMapping>OffsetDateTime=java.time.Instant</typeMapping>
                </typeMappings>
                <skipValidateSpec>false</skipValidateSpec>
                <globalProperties>
                  <skipFormModel>false</skipFormModel>
                </globalProperties>
                <configOptions>
                  <delegatePattern>true</delegatePattern>
                  <title>my-service</title>
                  <useSpringBoot3>true</useSpringBoot3>
                  <hideGenerationTimestamp>true</hideGenerationTimestamp>
                </configOptions>
              </configuration>
...

This generates DTOs effectively enough and mostly as expected with accessors and mutators, as well as some nice chain methods, but for one annoyance: there isn't a way to get all the properties of the DTO as a Map<String, Object>. This feels like it could be a configuration option in the generator, maybe, but not default.
Currently, I've written a private method to my implementation that uses Java Reflection to get the accessors and Map their values with invoke. But... is there a cleaner way in the use of the generator?
